# Quando se fazer perguntas a respeito de Sistema operacional, qual é o critério para fechamento como "Fora de escopo"?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, escopo-do-site

Eu realmente precisava que nessa pergunta houvesse uma resposta em relação a descobrir se uma porta está aberta ou não.

[Como saber se uma porta está aberta ou não no Linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107682/como-saber-se-uma-porta-est%C3%A1-aberta-ou-n%C3%A3o-no-linux?noredirect=1#comment221967_107682)

Aí um usuário comentou que essa pergunta está fora de escopo.

Qualquer pergunta sobre sistema operacional no site seria considerada *fora de escopo*?

Ou por acaso, pelo fato de o sistema operacional está, de alguma forma, ligada com a programação (nesse caso, por querer saber se meu script está rodando, para funcionamento do meu websocket em HTML5), essa pergunta pode ser considerada "válida"?

Comment: Eu acho que está dentro do escopo.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4749/a-dificuldade-singular-de-julgar-uma-quest%C3%A3o-dentro-de-contexto-ou-fora-de-conte

Comment: Também acho que essa pergunta está no escopo.

Comment: Alguns tratam a norma ao pé da letra e gera essa confusão. Se formos pensar que a sua pergunta específica está fora de escopo por não ser algo sobre programação, então, por exemplo, todas as outras perguntas sobre htaccess, configurar apache, etc, também são fora de escopo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters depende dos usuários que votam tambem. Um dia você pode perguntar de manhã e a comunidade te dar 3 respostas, no outro dia pode fazer à tarde e ela ser fechada em meia hora, no dia seguinte pode acontecer justo o inverso, e assim o mundo vai girando. Algumas pessoas não entendem que mais importante do que as regras, é o o motivo delas terem sido criadas. E é este motivo que deveria determina como e quando usar estas mesmas regras.

Comment: Não sei na época, mas hoje é fora do escopo. Deixei até uma orientação nos comentários. 